# How to use exists and not exists in tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I am struggling with exists and not exists in tableau the way I can do that in DB query. I posted the sample data here.

I want to find out which and how many locations have ABC and ABCD.

Which and How many locations have ABCD12345678, ABCD1 and not ABC.

I could have multiple combinations like that. Can anyone help me with this requirement?

HNS_LOCATION_ID HNS_PRODUCT_CODE

1000682 ABC

1000682 ABCD

1000682 ABCD1

1000682 ABCD12

1000682 ABCD123

1000682 ABCD1234

1000682 ABCD12345

1000682 ABCD123456

1000682 ABCD1234567

1000683 ABCD

1000683 ABCD1234567

1000683 ABCD12

1000683 ABCD1

1000683 ABCD1234

1000683 ABCD123456

1000683 ABCD12345

1000683 ABCD123

1000683 ABC

1000685 ABCD

1000685 ABCD12

1000685 ABCD1234567

1000685 ABCD1

1000685 ABCD12345

1000685 ABCD123

1000685 ABCD1234

1000685 ABCD123456

1000685 ABCD12345678

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your second case, just define a calculated field called, say, **meets_criteria** as:

```
max([HNS_PRODUCT_CODE] = "ABCD12345678") and
max([HNS_PRODUCT_CODE] = "ABCD1") and
not max([HNS_PRODUCT_CODE] = "ABCD")
```

Since True is considered greater than False, this calculation indicates whether your criteria is satisfied. (You can read max(condition) as "At least one row satisfies condition.")

There are different ways to use this calculated field. For example, you could put meets_criteria on Rows, and HNS_LOCATION_ID on Text to see locations that meet and do not meet criteria. (assuming you are treating HNS_LOCATION_ID as a dimension)

You could define a set named **locations_matching_criteria** based on the HNS_LOCATION_ID field, and use the meets_criteria calculation as the condition to define it. Literally, right click HNS_LOCATION_ID in the data pane, choose create set, select use all from the radio buttons on the general tab, then go to the condition tab and use the meets_criteria calculation field as the condition. That set now consists of your matching locations.

And then you can use the set in formulas and to build your vizzes — say, put your set on rows and COUNTD(HNS_LOCATION_ID) on Columns. There are lots of interesting ways to use sets

Comment: Thank you Alex.  If I follow this suggestion "For example, you could put meets_criteria on Rows, and HNS_LOCATION_ID on Text to see locations that meet and do not meet criteria. (assuming you are treating HNS_LOCATION_ID as a dimension)"  I get which location ids meet the criteria. How can I count how many locations meet the criteria? I want to put the count in one sheet and create a filter to navigate to another sheet that has details.

Comment: See the revised answer.